# FindAsync - CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm facing a very strange problem with my application...

I don't know why I'm getting this error message when I hit the FindAsync function:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.**

```
public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUser(string userName, string password)
{
    IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
    return user;
}
```

This is very strange, first of all I really don't realize how possible a command like that can try to create a database... It makes no sense!

The problem come out when I switch the application to a different database:

The application was and is still running properly on production database and infrastructure.
Now I have made a backup/restore of production data to development environmenet in order to apply some change and I started to get that error.

Both application are alligned... This is a strange behavior...

Its really no sense, how can a command like FindAsync try to create a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind this is, that the user manager will create a `DbContext` to query for the user and this context will try to create the DB if it does not exist.

As this was caused by switching the DB I guess you missed to also switch the DB used by the user manager.

To change that behavior you need to change the database initializer to `null` (`CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` is the default):

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Comment: Thanks man, your rock! The problem was that I was distracted and I put the wrong dbname in connection.
But I don't understand why it try to create the db... Can I disable this kind of feature somewhere? I want to have the complete control of the application...

Comment: public AuthContext()
            : base("AuthContext")
        {

        }

Comment: @DarioN1 You can also add it just somewhere before the DbContext is created the first time...